# Vector equivalent of complex multiplication and division

Tags: complex-numbers, vectors

I understand that the addition and subtraction of complex number is the same as vector addition and subtraction. But what is the vector equivalent of multiplication and division of complex numbers?

Comment: If you're looking for a geometric interpretation of multiplication, then if you express the complex numbers in polar form, $z_1 = r_1 \exp(i\theta_1)$ and $z_2 = r_2 \exp(i\theta_2)$, then $z_1 z_2 = r_1 r_2 \exp(i\theta_1 + i\theta_2)$. So the magnitudes multiply, and the angles add.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, there is none. In some cases, as in the case of complex numbers and of quaternions, such operations can be defined. And in the case of quaternions, you have two divisions, not just one (if $q$ and $r$ are quaternions and $r\ne0$, then, in general, $qr^{-1}\ne r^{-1}q$ since the product is not commutative in this case).

Comment: `In some cases, as in the case of complex numbers...can be defined` - Do you mean converting to polar form?

Answer (score 1):

You asked

> But what is the vector equivalent of multiplication and division of complex numbers?

The Wikipedia article on [William Rowan Hamilton](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/William_Rowan_Hamilton) states

> Hamilton was looking for ways of extending complex numbers (which can be viewed as points on a 2-dimensional plane) to higher spatial dimensions. He failed to find a useful 3-dimensional system (in modern terminology, he failed to find a real, three-dimensional skew-field), but in working with four dimensions he created quaternions.

It also states

> In pure mathematics, quaternions show up significantly as one of the four finite-dimensional normed division algebras over the real numbers, with applications throughout algebra and geometry.

The answer is that the vector equivalent is given by quaternions which are
an extension of three dimensional vectors, but with significant limitations.
For example, multiplication and division of
quaternions is not commutative. Also, vector quaternions are **not**
closed under products and quotients. The Wikipedia article [History of quaternions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_quaternions) states

> In 1843, Hamilton knew that the complex numbers could be viewed as points in a plane and that they could be added and multiplied together using certain geometric operations. Hamilton sought to find a way to do the same for points in space. Points in space can be represented by their coordinates, which are triples of numbers and have an obvious addition, but Hamilton had difficulty defining the appropriate multiplication.

and further on

> While he could not "multiply triples", he saw a way to do so for quadruples. By using three of the numbers in the quadruple as the points of a coordinate in space, Hamilton could represent points in space by his new system of numbers.

So, in general, there is no vector equivalent of multiplication and division,
however, you may find [geometric algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_algebra)
of interest where vectors and scalars are generalized to algebraic systems
where multiplication is defined, but division is not.